# Free tool to watch directory and show changes in files

Tags: file, directory, filesystemwatcher

Im looking for a tool that will watch directory(with sub-dirs) and give me the list of files that has changed and what has changed in them. Ive found some tools that show me files that has changed, but that is not enough for me.

P.S. I dont want to write it if someone has already written it.

P.S.2. Feel free to close this question if you are bored, however it is programming related since I need that tool to analize complicated data-structure of eclipse-plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to check all your files (i.e your eclipse installation dir) into a VCS like Git or subversion and run a `git diff` or `svn diff`, respectively. Combine this with live information from `inotify-tools` and you have got a decent setup. I don't know of any integrated solutions though.

Comment: that is a really great idea, git should be great to this since it doesnt need server to work.